# Downloaded files from firebase storage aren't readable

Tags: android

i succesfully download files from firebase storage and save it but the downloaded file which is pdf type isn't openable

here is the method

```
@Override
public void download(Book book) {
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Books");
    if(!root.exists()){
        root.mkdir();
    }

    storage.getReference().child(book.getmTitle()+".pdf").getFile(new File(root,book.getmTitle())).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Downloaded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

i am sure that the book.getmTitle() returns the reference name without the extension 'pdf'

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake, all what i had to do is to add the extension to the file name